# Keep Text in TextArea in Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Chrome extension popups are designed [per the FAQ](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-persist-popups) to close when clicked away from.

I have a firefox add-on that will remember the text typed into the text area when the popup is clicked open or closed.

I assume this is the case because the popup merely opens and closes the html, as opposed to the chrome version which calls `window.onload` each time.

The chrome extension popup however seems to call popup.js each time you click the icon, which I assume is because popup.js is linked from popup.html because page scripts have to be "moved out" in chrome for security.

Is there a way to keep data typed into a textbox, when the extension reloads and "erases" the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime the content of the textarea changes, store the new value in `localStorage`. When the popup loads again, check local storage for a value and populate the textarea.